# Is there an Android Test Orchestrator that restarts process for each class but not for each test?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-instrumentation, android-test-orchestrator

I know of two ways to run Android Instrumented tests:

- Default - no orchestartor. The same app process lives throughout the lifetime of the test suite
- With [AndroidX Test Orchestator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests/androidx-test-libraries/runner#use-android). The app is killed and restarted for each test.

The latter takes a significant toll on execution time of the test suite. Is there an alternative in between these two options, where for instance the app is killed only between each test class, but not for each test?